# Scrollbar filling in the Y direction, but not in the X direction. TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make two scrollbars one horizontal and one vertical.
They both work and get placed properly, but the horizontal one only takes up a very small portion of the screen (which is not good), but the vertical one takes up the whole height of the screen.
Here's my code for the display:

```
    def showTerms(self):
        self.clearFrame()
        countx= 0
        county=0
        frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.framesHold[3] = frame    
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1)

        my_canvas = Canvas(self.framesHold[3])
        my_canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.framesHold[3], orient = VERTICAL, command = my_canvas.yview)
        yscrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.framesHold[3], orient = HORIZONTAL, command = my_canvas.xview)
        xscrollbar.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = 'x')

        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))


        frame2 = tk.Frame(my_canvas)

        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame2, anchor = "nw")
        my_canvas.config(width=frame2.winfo_width(), height=frame2.winfo_height())
```

A few things to note are that I have an external list that holds frames so please treat `self.framesHold[3]` as a normal frame.
Thank you :)

Comment: The order that you call `pack` matters, try packing the canvas last.

Comment: @BryanOakley That did it, thank you so much! I'm just wondering why the yscrollbar worked but the x one didn't even thought the canvas was packed before both?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the order in which you pack widgets matters. Each time you call `pack` it will allocate an entire side of whatever space hasn't been filled up yet.

When you called `pack` on the canvas, it takes up the entire left side of the containing frame. When you pack the scrollbar on the right, it takes the entire right side. The only space available becomes the space between these two widgets. Since the minimum size of the horizontal widget is only a few dozen pixels, that's all it is allocated.

The simple solution for this specific layout, and when using `pack`, is to pack the horizontal and vertical scrollbars first, and then add the canvas last.

pro tip: if you collect all of your calls to `pack` (or `grid`, or `place`) into groups based on the parent, this becomes a trivial change to make, and lets you easily experiment with the different ordering of the widgets. Plus, in my experience it's much easier to visualize the layout when looking at the code since all layout is grouped together.

```
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X, padx=(0, yscrollbar.winfo_width()))
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

As an added exercise, see what happens if you call `grid` on the horizontal scrollbar first to see how the order changes things. Look at the bottom-right corner to see the difference.